# How to parse json into panda dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following json structure that I'm trying to parse:

```
[
 {
"id": 0,
"cuisine": "greek",
"ingredients": [
  "romaine lettuce",
  "black olives",
  "feta cheese crumbles"
]
},
{
"id": 1,
"cuisine": "southern_us",
"ingredients": [
  "plain flour",
  "ground pepper",
  "milk",
  "vegetable oil"
]
}....]
```

There's thousands of values in this JSON-file and I want to parse it into a panda dataframe. How would I go about doing that considering there's a nested list under the ingredients key.

Cheers :)

Comment: Parsing the file should produce a basic python data structure - a list of dictionaries, etc.  Import the `json` module and use its `load`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OR:

```
pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame,json))
```

Example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> json=[
 {
"id": 0,
"cuisine": "greek",
"ingredients": [
  "romaine lettuce",
  "black olives",
  "feta cheese crumbles"
]
},
{
"id": 1,
"cuisine": "southern_us",
"ingredients": [
  "plain flour",
  "ground pepper",
  "milk",
  "vegetable oil"
]
}]
>>> pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame,json))
       cuisine  id           ingredients
0        greek   0       romaine lettuce
1        greek   0          black olives
2        greek   0  feta cheese crumbles
0  southern_us   1           plain flour
1  southern_us   1         ground pepper
2  southern_us   1                  milk
3  southern_us   1         vegetable oil
>>>
```

Comment: Legend! Thanks :)

Comment: @Hews Thanks, happy that i helped, 

Answer (score 1):

This is list of dict not json

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in js])
Out[156]: 
       cuisine  id           ingredients
0        greek   0       romaine lettuce
1        greek   0          black olives
2        greek   0  feta cheese crumbles
0  southern_us   1           plain flour
1  southern_us   1         ground pepper
2  southern_us   1                  milk
3  southern_us   1         vegetable oil
```